# make available a method of an object

Tags: javascript

please help to fix the [script](http://jsfiddle.net/vE52N/).

the problem is that it is impossible to call a function scoreChange ()

my singleton method returns scoreChange () instruction return. but it does not help

console displays a message here error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: scoreChange is not defined

js:

```
var Player = (function (){
    var instance;

    function init() {
        return {
            x: 500,
            y: 500,
            health: 100,
            bullets: 50,
            speed: 10,
            score: 0,

            render: function(x, y){
                $('#player').css({
                    'left': (x || this.x) + 'px',
                    'top': (y || this.y) + 'px'
                }); 

                return;                 
            },  

            scoreChange: function(score){
                $('.score').text(score);
            },

            init: function(){
                if($('#player').length == 0){
                    $('<div class="ship_player" id="player" />').appendTo('#wrap');
                }   

                this.render(500, 500);

                return;         
            }
        };
    };

    return {
        getInstance: function (){
            if ( !instance ){
                instance = init();
            }

            return instance;
        },

        scoreChange: scoreChange
    };
})();

var player = Player.getInstance();

player.init();      

player.scoreChange(100);
```

Comment: why you add   `scoreChange: scoreChange` after `return instance`.you can't do anything after return in a function .it's almost returned

Comment: Those curly braces are object delimiters not block delimiters. The return value is an object with two methods : getInstance and scoreChange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find your Player function was returning your object with `getInstance`, but `Player` itself is a function. Therefore unless you've attached a value to `this.varname` then you can't access `Player.varname` as you are attempting to do with `Player.getInstance()`

As an indication of how this is wrongly phrased, note that `Player().getInstance()` would've made more semantic sense, as the `Player` function has then been called and you've been returns a handle to the object with `getInstance` as one of it's fields.

I would rewrite this like so.

```
var Player = function($player) {
  if (Player.prototype._singletonInstance)
    return Player.prototype._singletonInstance;
  Player.prototype._singletonInstance = this;

  this.$player = $player;
  this.x = 500; this.y = 500;
  this.stats = {
    speed:   10,   score:    0,
    health: 100,   bullets: 50,
  };

  this.render = function render(x,y) {
    this.$player.css({
        'left': (this.x = x || this.x) + 'px',
        'top':  (this.y = y || this.y) + 'px'
    });
    return this;
  };

  this.changeScore = function changeScore(score) {
    $('.score').text(this.stats.score = score);
  };

};

var player = new Player($('#player'));
var _player = new Player();
if (player === _player)
  console.log('Successful singleton');
player.changeScore(100); // success
```

Also I'd recommend using events to bind the `$('.score')` elements to the Players score value. So in your `changeScore` method you would emit an event such as `scoreChanged`, and each of your dom elements representing the score could listen for that event and adjust themselves appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Set `scoreChange` as Global

```
var Player = (function () {
var instance;
var scoreChange;
```

ALSO

```
 return {
    getInstance: function () {
    if (!instance) {
    instance = init();
    }
    scoreChange: scoreChange; // add this line before return statement 
    return instance;
    },
};
```